# Change scope value in a different view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, steroids

Ok, I have struggeled a lot with this thing for some days now and I'm stuck. Here is what I want; I want to change my scope value in a different view by clicking on a button. So if I'm in the index.html view and click on a button I want to change the value of a scope on the index2.html view, and then display that view. Here is an example of my code which is not working

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="checkValues()" value="checkitems" >
  check values
</button>
</div>
```

IndexController.js

```
angular
  .module('legeApp')
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic, $filter) {  

 $scope.checkValues = function(){   

     $scope.Diagnose = 'test';

        var view = new supersonic.ui.View("legeApp#index2.html");
        var customAnimation = supersonic.ui.animate("flipHorizontalFromLeft");
        supersonic.ui.layers.push(view, { animation: customAnimation });
    };
});
```

index2.html

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    Test<b>{{Diagnose}} </b>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

I can give the value outside the checkValues method, but I want it to be two different values depending on the button you click. Please help

I tried the code suggested, but I received an error. What am I doing wrong?

I try the code below and receive this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' - undefined:undefined". I also did not quite understand how and why I want to target the new value with supersonic.ui.views.params.current in the new view. I want to get the new value in the new view, not in a controller?Do I need two different controllers? I just want to update my values in a html view without being in it.

```
supersonic.ui.layers.push: 
( view: view, 
options: { params: {$scope.Diagnose : 'test'} 
animation: customAnimation 
}) => Promise
```

Comment: will need a service for that. Each controller instance runs indepependantly of other instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the supersonic push [docs](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/ui/layers/push/), the `params` attribute is meant for passing parameters between views:

```
JSON string of optional parameters to be passed to the target View, 
accessible via supersonic.ui.views.params.current.
```

Try calling

```
supersonic.ui.layers.push: (
  view: view,
  options: {
    params: {valueToBeSentAccrossView: <Your Value>}
    animation: customAnimation
}) => Promise
```

and then retrieving the value in the target view using `supersonic.ui.views.params.current`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to make it work. I try the code below and receive this error  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' - undefined:undefined". I also did not quite understand how and why I want to target the new value with supersonic.ui.views.params.current in the new view. I want to get the new value in the new view, not in a controller?Do I need two different controllers? I just want to update my values in a html view without being in it.   supersonic.ui.layers.push: (
    view: view,
    options: {
      params: {$scope.Diagnose : 'test'}
      animation: customAnimation
  }) => Promise

Comment: I update the post with the comment so its easier to see.